# How to create a list that contains the first word of every line in a file (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

The file is called "emotion_words" which I want the first word of each line for.
I want to use a nested for loop, but I am not sure how.
Would I do this

```
emotions=open("emotion_words.txt","r+")
content = emotions.read()
for line in content.split(' ',1):
```

And add an append function before the second for loop?

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("emotion_words.txt","r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        first_word_in_line = line.split(" ")[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fileref = open ("emotion_words.txt","r")
line = fileref.readlines()
emotions = []
for words in line:
    word = words.split()
    emotions.append(word[0])
print (emotions)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, this should work for you:

```
words = []
emotions = open("emotion_words.txt", "r+")
for l in emotions:
    first_word = l.split()[0]
    words.append(first_word)
```

After that you have your words in a 'words' list.